# Need help in creating regex of alpha numeric numbers

Tags: python, regex

I need to create a regex for alpha-numeric characters like below:

```
AB12C0064- 1
AC23D0034- 2
AB45E5421- 4
```

Can someone help to create regex for this kind of pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the same pattern is following,

```
import re
a = """"
AB12C0064- 1 sdflj
AC23D0034- 2
AB45E5421- 4
asfda
"""
re.findall("[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{4}- [0-9]{1}",a)
```

Outputs

```
['AB12C0064- 1', 'AC23D0034- 2', 'AB45E5421- 4']
```

Answer (score 0):

[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{4} exactly matches your requirement explanation for each patter used is as follows
[A-Z]{2}-  {2} Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times A-Z a single character in the range between A to Z  (Including A and Z)
[0-9]{2}-  {2} Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times 0-9 a single character in the range between 0 to 9 (Including 0 and 9)
[A-Z]{1}- {1} Quantifier — Matches exactly one time A-Z a single character in the range between A to Z  (Including A and Z)
[0-9]{4}- {4} Quantifier — Matches exactly 4 times 0-9 a single character in the range between 0 to 9 (Including 0 and 9)

Details explanation for regular expression for Patter Used you can refer into following links which helps you in building and Testing regular expressions.
https://regex101.com/
https://regexr.com/